# How can i register a click and at the same time update the click counter table in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm trying to create a project voting app and I need users to vote on the most popular proposals. So I need a click counter on each of the proposals.  A example with the iris dataset where Sepal.Length is the record clicked.

```
library(shiny)
library(reactable)

iris2 = iris #to start
saveRDS(iris2, paste0(getwd(),'/iris.Rds'))
iris2 = readRDS(paste0(getwd(),'/iris2.Rds'))


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("row selection example"),
  reactableOutput("table"),
  verbatimTextOutput("selected")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  selected <- reactive(getReactableState("table", "selected"))
  
  output$table <- renderReactable({
    reactable(x(), selection = "single", onClick = "select")
  })
  
  observe({
    iris2[selected(), "Sepal.Length"] =     iris2[selected(), "Sepal.Length"] +1
    print(iris2[selected(), ])
    saveRDS(iris2,paste0(getwd(),'/iris2.Rds'))
  })
  
  x <- reactivePoll(2000, session,
                    checkFunc = function() {
                      if (file.exists(paste0(getwd(),'/iris2.Rds')))
                        file.info(paste0(getwd(),'/iris2.Rds'))$mtime[1]
                      else
                        ""
                    },
                    valueFunc = function() {
                      iris2=readRDS(paste0(getwd(),'/iris2.Rds'))
                    }
  ) 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

My problem is that the app records the vote, but then goes back to the original record and doesn't count the vote. how can i stop shiny from going back to the original record and at the same time update the voting table?

Comment: Can you please make this example reproducible by removing the dependence on a local rds file, or add the code to create it first

Comment: @RemkoDuursma .Thank you for your note.  I removed the dependence on a local rds file to make this example more reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have 2 main problems:

- The version you save is not the latest version plus the vote, but you always start from the original `iris2`, because iris2 is modified only inside the `observe` bloc. If you want to modify the general variable, you will need to use `<<-` (or in a more cleaner way maybe a reactive variable)
- The observe run once it's updated because the modification reset the selection. You need to stop the observe if the selected is empty (actually it seems cleaner anyway)

You observe becomes like that:

```
  observe({
    selection <- selected()
    if(!is.null(selection)) {
      iris2[selection, "Sepal.Length"]  <<- iris2[selection, "Sepal.Length"] + 1
      print(iris2[selection, ])
      saveRDS(iris2, paste0(getwd(),'/iris2.Rds'))
    }
  })
```